# Redefine a primitive parameter

Tags: macros, tex-core, parameters

I want to redefine a primitive parameter as a macro, and make the macro behaves the same as the primitive parameter in some situations.

```
\tracingcommands = 1
\the\tracingcommands
\ifnum\tracingcommands > 0 true\fi

\let\oldtracingcommands\tracingcommands
\def\tracingcommands{\afterassignment\temp\count255}
\def\temp{\oldtracingcommands\count255 \domore}
\def\domore{}

\tracingcommands = 1 % success
\the\tracingcommands % failure
\ifnum\tracingcommands > 0 true\fi % failure
```

In running the above example, the last two lines failed. How could these be resolved?

Comment: If `\p` is primitive and you say `\let\q\p` then isn't `\q` just defined as `\p`, so that if you then redefine `\p`, `\q` will follow? I don't know anything about it, but how else could it work? `\q` must be defined as something and if `\p` is irreducible, then `\q` must surely be defined as `\p`?

Comment: The failure `\the\tracingmacros` is because `\tracingmacros` is no longer what it used to be. Using `\the\oldtracingmacros` would do the trick. However, could you explain what you want as well since it's not clear from the code snippet? For example, if you wish to redefine primitives, how about doing it inside a group so their meanings are restored upon closure?

Comment: The `\the` primitive can be followed by internal register, but not by the macro. Respect the primitive syntax and think about your problem from another side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, provided you use `\the` when the command is used in a `<number>` context.

```
\let\textracingcommands\tracingcommands
\def\tracingcommands{\tctoks={\tcgobble}\afterassignment\tcdo\textracingcommands}
\def\tcdo{DONE}
\def\tcgobble#1#2#3#4{\the}
\newtoks\tctoks
\tctoks={\tcgobble}

\tracingcommands=3

\the\tracingcommands

\ifnum\the\tracingcommands<2 SMALL\else BIG\fi

\bye
```

Why you would do this is quite dubious to begin with.

[image]